# How to make copyright box stick to bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make this HTML container stick to the bottom of the page (not the screen, the page)

i.e. A page that scrolls a fair length and the container is at the bottom, but also a page which does not require scrolling, the container is still at the bottom.

I have this code:

```css
.copyright-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="copyright-container">
  <div class="vert-align">
    <p class="headline">
      Copyright &copy; 2017 RyanTeaches - All Rights Reserved.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem with absolute is that while this works fine on pages with little content, and page where I have to scroll, it scrolls up too - it sits at the bottom of the screen, not the bottom of the page.

I also tried using "fixed" but this meant the container remained on the screen the whole time.

I then tried "relative" and while this worked correctly for the page that needed scrolling, and sat it at the bottom, the page with little content, it sat halfway up the page.

Comment: Provide image view

Comment: Richard - have edited with code. Akash - what do you mean by image view? (New to this)

Comment: I think your copyright-container is on the middle of the screen if the page is not hight enough?
If that's true, you have to increase the heigt of you body element.
Beacuse position:absolute positions the elemente absolute to the next parent relative positioned element like body

Comment: If you would like to see what is happening currently - please visit http://ryanteaches.com/gcsechemistry.html

To see the difference on a page with little content thus far, on the nav bar go to more--> about me as that is currently a blank page. You can edit the code locally by right click --> view page source or press F12

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem, you need to use javascript:

Put the element normally at the end of the flow and it will be at the bottom of the page like you want: However, when the content is too small, you need to position your element fixed to be at the bottom of the screen. You can do that after the load of the page.

It makes something like that in JQuery:

```
$( window ).load(function() {
  if ($(window).height() > $('#content').height() + $('#navigation').height()) {
    $('.copyright-container').css({
      position: 'fixed'
      bottom: 0
    });
  }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help - that fixed it for the page that requires scrolling. However for a page with little content so far: http://ryanteaches.com/gcsebiology.html - both my white box and subscribe box are now sitting over my #content container? - not below it as expected. The #content is set to relative and contains text

Comment: In this case, where do you want the copyright to sit? After the content or at the bottom of the screen? Sorry, I think I misunderstood a point here...

Comment: I want it to always be at the bottom of the page/content (not the screen) when I have to scroll, but at the bottom of the screen when I dont have to scroll

Comment: Nevermind - it seems the fix is to just have more content - which thinking about it I will have plenty of content so that should work fine! Thank you very much :)

Comment: Ahah that's the most pragmatic solution indeed :) I have updated my answer to handle this case using jquery. Check if the answer suits you so that your vote won't misguide some people if it's not what you wanted! BTW, on your website, when you have a header with a fixed position, it's better IMHO to add a padding-top once on the content that equals the height of the header rather than using a relative positioning, so all the following content will be well placed